# Compile greasemonkey script into xpi to save file?

Tags: greasemonkey

if i compile a greasemonkey script into an xpi, then can that xpi access to local file to read and write files from hard disk???

question 2, if i save data using SetValue API of GM then do i need to del the value or does it gets deleted automatically when i restart the FireFox browser??

Answer (score 1):

> if i compile a greasemonkey script into an xpi, then can that xpi access to local file to read and write files from hard disk???

yes it could, because it is then a firefox extension, but it would mean that you need to decompress the xpi file, and modify the code to access the file system.

> question 2, if i save data using SetValue API of GM then do i need to del the value or does it gets deleted automatically when i restart the FireFox browser??

If you create a value then it will remain until you delete the value, regardless of browser restarts.