# Local file access and compiling a greasemonkey script to xpi

Tags: javascript, file-io, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

I want to provide some functionality through an extension. This requires (read and execute) access to some resource files (an mp3 file, a swf file and two js).

I know user scripts cannot access local files and I need an extension (add-on) to do that.
But can I start by writing a greasemonkey script and compiling it to a xpi?
How should I specify the path to the file for it to work when compiled into an xpi?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510830/compile-greasemonkey-script-into-xpi-to-save-file) is close to what I'm trying to do, but does not say anything about the path.
Yet [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491490/how-to-use-jquery-in-firefox-extension) discusses how to add resources to your xpi, but assumes you write the xpi from scratch not if you compile a greasmonkey user script to an xpi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with greasemonkey, however I have successfully written to files using a FireFox addon. Once you have a FireFox addon which you can modify, you can see the page here: [File I/O - MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO) for some help writing files via the API in FireFox. I use the nsiFilePicker service to select the file/path.

Comment: Link no-longer available